# Digital light organ

Tags: digital-logic, analog, light

I am trying to make a circuit that takes an audio signal from an MP3 player and converts the signal into digital signals based on frequency.

[image: First draft of design]
Audio In is the is the signal from the audio jack of an android phone.
D9, D10, and D12 are all inputs of the [ADAfruit Flora](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-flora).

I suppose what I am asking for is critique of this design.

Comment: What is the AC voltage swing at the input? What DC bias do you have on that line?

Comment: @sherrellbc The AC voltage swing is whatever comes out of a mobile phone audio jack. I have no DC bias on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty standard **Color Organ** circuit. A buffer stage, going into three RC band-pass filters, to transistor based led sections. While op-amps might be better than transistors, it should still work.

Comment: There is one band-pass, one low-pass, and one high-pass filter. Wouldn't the 'band-pass' filter on the bottom have issues? The second stage would load the first would it not?

Comment: @sherrellbc low-pass and high-pass filters are just specific types of band-pass filters.

Comment: @Passerby: Perhaps, but right now that's irrelevant.  In the real world and in simple terms, a filter with an output amplitude which decreases as its input frequency increases is called a "low pass filter",  a filter with an output amplitude which increases as its input frequency increases is called a "high pass filter", and  a filter with an output amplitude which decreases as its input frequency rises and falls beyond certain points is called a "bandpass filter".

Comment: @EMFields why are you arguing literal semantics? If you want to do that, you should also argue about the oxymoronic use of "pass filter".

Comment: You seem to deliberately misconstrue constructive criticism as being argumentative when, in fact, it was issued in order to clarify the issue of the inappropriate contextual muddling of technical terms. As for the rest of it, you seem to think you've had your feathers ruffled and are champing at the bit for some sort of retribution, but I'll have none of it and I consider the matter closed.

Comment: @EMFields whatever you say buddy